# images, css and js files are not being loaded in my application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, image, iis, iis-7.5

This one is killing me, neither of those files are loaded in my application: images, css, js, everything was working fine before re-installing my PC, so I guess is configuration issue with IIS, since i haven't touch code and works well in a PC of a co-worker.

When seeing the HTML in firebug I see this

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost/Common/Scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js
```

this is the code

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am running Windows 7 and IIS 7.5, it's an Asp.Net MVC 3 Application.

I have tried the following

- uninstall and re-install IIS
- added read permission on file system to IUSR and IIS_USRS
- In the application in IIS, in feature anonymous authentication, I selected "application pool indentity".

Nothing happens, maybe someone has another idea of what's happening.

Or at least point me a direction to better understand the reason of the problem and I will update the question with the feedback.

help will be appreciated... and rewarded :)

thanks

Comment: are your scripts located inside the `Common` dir?

Comment: actually Common is the application, I have them located in Scripts dir.

Comment: put this `http://localhost/Common/Scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js` in your browser address box and check do u can see the file ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem.

I didn't mark Static Content in features for IIS.

In Windows Features go to, Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Common HTTP Features > Static Content

Under Application Development Features I selected Asp.Net it selected automatically everything else, I wonder why It didn't select this option too.

Hope it helps to someone else.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, it was driving me nuts!  And you're right, why on earth wouldn't it be installed by default.

Comment: SO saves the day again :)